# Makefile don't print flags

Tags: makefile

How can I get make to not print flags.

Example:

```
prettycolors:
    @echo -e "\e[32mIM GREEN\e[0m"
```

Current behavior:

```
$ make prettycolors
-e IM GREEN
```

Desired behavior:

```
$ make prettycolors
IM GREEN
```

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable (not defined by POSIX).  In fact, there is NO portable way to use `echo` print anything other than a simple string that doesn't begin with a dash (all options like `-e`, `-n`, etc. are not portable).  If you want to print special characters you should use `printf`, not `echo`, which is defined by POSIX and will work the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like shell does not accept echo flags.

You can either specify echo you want to use: (in `Makefile`)

```
ECHO=/bin/echo

prettycolors:
    @$(ECHO) -e "\e[32mIM GREEN\e[0m"
```

or specify "smarter" shell:

```sh
$ make SHELL=/bin/bash prettycolors
```